# Are there any tips that I can use to know when to use among or in?

Tags: prepositions

"Having a boring life causes depression **in/among** children"

I made that sentence, and am not sure which is the right preposition to use.

It seems that "in" can be used to talk about people having diseases, for example "*Excessive junk food consumption combined with a lack of exercise leads to diabetes **in** children*".

Comment: See [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/292289/in-vs-among).

Answer (score 2):

'Children' is not only the plural of 'child' - when you use 'children' as a group or collective noun, it is a singular thing.

You can be 'in' a group, but 'among' individuals. 'Among' recognises the individuals within a group. Think of this - you can be *in* a car. You can't be 'among' a car.

Your specific example should use 'in'. This is because it is saying that something causes a certain result in a particular *group* of the population, children.

You tend to see 'among' used in similar contexts when the group is not as strictly defined. For example, "*there has been an outbreak of chicken pox among children*". This is because the illness is not limited to that group, but it is recognising that the individuals involved have largely been children.